# coding to solve parametric nonlinear programming

Tags: programming, nonlinear

I am new to mathematica. Can anyone please help me solve parametric nonlinear programming.

This is my objective function and constraints

```
max (x/y)[1-3(x/y)^2+2(x/y)^3]/[(1-(x/y)^3(1-x/y)]   
s.t. (8+α)/2 ≤ x ≤ (13-2α)/2,
8+α ≤ y ≤ 12-α
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax issues in your input. However `Maximize` is the function to be used. Here is the code:

```
Maximize[{
  (x/y) (1 - 3 (x/y)^2 + 2 (x/y)^3)/((1 - (x/y)^3 (1 - x/y))),
  (8 + α)/2 <= x <= (13 - 2 α)/2,
   8 + α <= y <= 12 - α}, {x, y}]
```

When evaluated, *Mathematica* does give the solution quickly, but it is a very complex solution involving `Piecewise` functions, inequalities, `Root` objects etc.. Is this the correct and complete system you want to solve ? Are you missing out any additional conditions?

Comment: Thankyou so much sir..  i got the answer... i pointed out one error after viewing your comment.. actually i missed one constrain.. my x and y value should be strictly greater than zero.. so after adding "x >0,y>0" in the constrain part i got the right solution.. thanks a lot